# How to transform a list: numpy.int64 instance into (sparse/binary) categorial format for model.fit?

Tags: python, list, tensorflow, keras, nlp

I am working with Tensorflow to make text classification. I want to make use of tensorflow hub. I am using the imdb_reviews dataset. My code so far is as follows:

```
import csv
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

imdb, info = tfds.load("imdb_reviews", with_info=True, as_supervised=True)

imdb_train=imdb['train']
imdb_test=imdb['test']

training_sentences=[]
training_labels=[]
test_sentences=[]
test_labels=[]

for a,b in imdb_train:
  training_sentences.append(a.numpy().decode("utf8"))
  training_labels.append(b.numpy())

for a,b in imdb_test:
  test_sentences.append(a.numpy().decode("utf8"))
  test_labels.append(b.numpy())

import tensorflow_hub as hub

model = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/gnews-swivel-20dim/1"
hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(model, output_shape=[20], input_shape=[], 
                           dtype=tf.string, trainable=True)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(hub_layer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(x=training_sentences,
                      y=training_labels,
                      validation_data=(test_sentences, test_labels),
                      epochs=2)
```

The model.fit command gives the error:

```
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'str'>"}), (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'numpy.int64'>"})
```

Reason is training_labels:

The training_sentences and test_sentences are in the following format/shape:

[image: ex1]

The training_labels and test_labels however, have the following format/shape:

[image: ex2]

and output looks like this:

[image: ex4]

I need training_labels (same for test_labels) in the following format/shape to make model.fit work:
[image: examp]

(output would look like this:)

[image: examp2]

and so on

Could also be `[[2], [1], [2], [1], [2], ...]` I would be fine with that too. Then I would use SparseCategoricalCrossentropy with units in last layer equal to 2 . Important is the format/shape.

How can I make this transformation?

I could make us of the Tokenizer and first transform the 0 1 to yes and no (or a and b doesn't matter) and then apply the Tokenizer and as a result get it in the format with values 1 and 2:

```
training_labels_test=[]
for i in training_labels:
   if i==0: training_labels_test.append("no")
   if i==1: training_labels_test.append("yes")
  
testtokenizer=Tokenizer()
testtokenizer.fit_on_texts(training_labels_test)
test_labels_pad=testtokenizer.texts_to_sequences(training_labels_test)

val_labels_test=[]
for i in test_labels:
   if i==0: val_labels_test.append("no")
   if i==1: val_labels_test.append("yes")

testtokenizer.fit_on_texts(val_labels_test)
val_labels_pad=testtokenizer.texts_to_sequences(val_labels_test)
```

[image: ex4]

However, tokenizing it is a workaround and I thought there must be a better way.

(Please note that I really want this way / asking about the actual transformation, so no workaround / other solution with using batches of imdb_train or tfds.as_numpy directly applied to the imdb dataset in the first step.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried out your code and you can do the following to achieve what you want.

```
for a,b in imdb_train:
  training_sentences.append(a.numpy().decode("utf8"))
  training_labels.append([b.numpy()])

for a,b in imdb_test:
  test_sentences.append(a.numpy().decode("utf8"))
  test_labels.append([b.numpy()])
```

This will give you following result for your labels as you asked for.

```
[[0], [0], [0], [1], [1]
```

But even after that and changing the loss function and changing the last layer I still received the following error

```
Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'str'>"}), (<class 'list'> containing values of types {'(<class \'list\'> containing values of types {"<class \'numpy.int64\'>"})'})
```

**UPDATE:**

After your comment, I tried the following code and I was able to train your model with the following code.

```
for a,b in imdb_train:
  training_sentences.append(a.numpy().decode("utf8"))
  training_labels.append([int(b.numpy())])

for a,b in imdb_test:
  test_sentences.append(a.numpy().decode("utf8"))
  test_labels.append([int(b.numpy())])
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate that you put brain energy into my problem. However, problem with that is that if you hover over it, you can see that it still has [numpy.int64 instance] in it. So it is the same shape/format as before (just with [ before and ] after numpy.int64 instance. It does not change it to the shape/format I need to avoid the error.

Comment: I have to add that I am using colab, so if I hover over it in colab I can see it. Not sure what you use and if you can see that.

Comment: I updated my answer and now the code at least works on my google colab. I hope it works on yours.

Comment: Thanks, I will check!

Comment: Happy to be a help.